# jQuery product filter using checkboxes and :contains() show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show-hide, contains

I'm attempting to put together a simple jQuery product filter for a store that lists all products of a category on one page. This can't be achieved through AJAX because of the way the store is set up.

Simply put, all products of the category are on one page. They have varying brands product names and team names. The markup looks something like this (the form at the end is how I'm planning on doing the filter).

```
<div id="CategoryContent">
<ul>

<li class="product">Brand1 PRODUCT1 TeamA</li>
<li class="product">Brand1 PRODUCT2 TeamB</li>
<li class="product">Brand2 PRODUCT3 TeamB</li>
<li class="product">Brand2 PRODUCT4 TeamC</li>
<li class="product">Brand3 PRODUCT5 TeamA</li>
<li class="product">Brand3 PRODUCT6 TeamD</li>
<li class="product">Brand4 PRODUCT7 TeamD</li>
<li class="product">Brand1 PRODUCT8 TeamA</li>
<li class="product">Brand1 PRODUCT9 TeamA</li>
<li class="product">Brand1 PRODUCT10 TeamB</li>
<li class="product">Brand4 PRODUCT11 TeamD</li>
<li class="product">Brand2 PRODUCT12 TeamA</li>
</ul>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="filter">
<form id= "brandfilter" action="">
    <h2>Brands:</h2>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Brand1"/>Brand1 </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Brand2"/>Brand2 </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Brand3"/>Brand3 </br>    
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Brand1"/>Brand4 </br>
</form>
<form id="teamfilter" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="team" value="TeamA"/>TeamA </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="team" value="TeamB"/>TeamB </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="team" value="TeamC"/>TeamC </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="team" value="TeamD"/>TeamD </br>
</form>
```

I have found this filter works as I want. In console replacing hide with show and Brand1 with Brand2, TeamA, etc works just fine.

```
$("#CategoryContent li").not(
$("#CategoryContent li:contains(Brand1)")
).hide();
```

The next step is getting a double filter which works as well:

```
$("#CategoryContent li").not(
$("#CategoryContent li:contains(Brand1):contains(TeamA)")
).hide();
```

My problem with getting this working is two fold. 1 is replacing the Brand1 / Team A with variables (hence the formids).

The second is trying to run the script when a checkbox is clicked. It should work if either one is clicked and if both are clicked (meaning that with the script above it would need to reset by showing all and then hiding).

Currently to initiate it I'm running this script but I'm running into problems so I've gone back to just 1 filter.

```
$("input:checkbox[name='brand']").click(function() {
    var brandfilter = $(this).val();
    alert (brandfilter);
    $("#CategoryContent li:contains('  + brandfilter + ')").parent().hide();
});
```

The alert that pops up is what I want (i.e. Brand1) but the hide function afterwards doesn't work and when I `alert (brandfilter)` again in console again I get `[object HTMLFormElement]`. So I think the variable isn't storing correctly or something?

Here is the simple working basic script http://jsfiddle.net/7gYJc/

Comment: Is the idea to show all the items that contain any of the checked values? e.g. What is supposed to happen if both the TeamA and TeamB boxes are checked?

Comment: Also, the value for Brand4 is incorrect. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to show items which match any currently ticked box, you can use this:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(showHideProducts);

function showHideProducts()
{
    var checked = $('input:checked');
    var products = $('.product');

    // If all the boxes are unchecked, show all the products.
    if (checked.length == 0)
    {
        products.show();
    }
    else
    {
        products.hide();
        checked.each
        (
            function()
            {
                $('.product:contains("' + $(this).val() + '")').show();
            }            
        );
    }
}​
```

**EDIT:** Since you want all the boxes to display when nothing is checked, just add an if (length = 0) check and show everything in there (see above).

Comment: Yes, so all items are shown when the page loads and all boxes are unticked. When a customer checks a box it will hide all other products and show the products that match the checkbox.

I like the look of this - I just can't get it to work. Can you show me on the jsfiddle link I posed.

Comment: Works well unless all boxes are unticked, then nothing displays.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell where the problem is but you can try using `filter()` instead of the `:contains` selector. With `filter()` you can create your own custom filtering rules as it takes a function as parameter.

```
var myProducts = function (brand, team) {

    brand = brand || '';
    team = team || '';

    return $('.product').filter(function () {
        var re = new RegExp(brand + '.+' + team, 'i');
        return re.test($(this).text());
    });

};

myProducts('Brand1', 'TeamA').hide();
myProducts('Brand2').hide();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/hYZcW/

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following approach:

Start with all the checkboxes checked, because you want to show all the products. If the user unticks a checkbox, then it should hide products matching that brand/team.

Here is the code I had:

```
var $filters = $("input:checkbox[name='brand'],input:checkbox[name=team]").prop('checked', true); // start all checked
var $categoryContent = $('#CategoryContent li'); // cache this selector
$filters.click(function() {
    // if any of the checkboxes for brand or team are checked, you want to show LIs containing their value, and you want to hide all the rest.
    $categoryContent.hide();
    $filters.filter(':checked').each(function(i, el) {
        $categoryContent.filter(':contains(' + el.value + ')').show();
    });
});​
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/3WcDC/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem this week with multiple selects. The selectors worked fine, but hide did not work. I was able to solve it using

```
.css('visibility', 'hidden'); // instead of .hide() and 
.css('visibility', ''); // instead of .show()
```

I do not understand it, but it worked.